# Возможно ли хранить данные в самом Solr?

Tags: solr

Я новичек в использовании Solr. Скажите, если мне нужен небольшой индекс (всего несколько сайтов), возможно ли хранить данные в самом Solr, без использования какой-либо БД?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, можно, но для этого нужно использовать Solr в связке с Nutch. http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial